# Prevent image from 'obscuring' onmouseover event below?

Tags: javascript

For a 'shooting gallery'-like game, there are images with an onMouseOver event that will show a crosshair (which follows the mouse) and an onMouseOut event that will hide it.

However, the instant the crosshair becomes visible, it covers the below image, activating its onMouseOut event which hides the crosshair.

This creates a 'flicker' effect which is very, very ugly.

Is there a way to prevent the crosshair image from obscuring the target below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to create an onMouseOver for the crosshair that shows it (I know this is redundant, but it works for menus and the like).

Another solution would be to set a timeout in the onMouseOut to hide the crosshair. It will reduce the flickering and the crosshair will be visible out of the target for a short time.

**Edit:**
And another would be to perform a collision detection between the mouse and the elements, changing the mouseOver to a mouseMove in the target's parent element:

http://jsfiddle.net/sHecT/1/

The code is quite long, but its logic is what I've said above.

Just a note: The `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in older browsers, but you can use an array of targets, as you create them, add them to an aray (probably you already has one) and use it in place of this call;

This one illustrates an easing function to position the crosshair smothly and the cursor is hidden when over the target

http://jsfiddle.net/sHecT/2/

Comment: After the mouse has left the image, the mouse would still be over the crosshair (because the crosshair would be following the mouse) and always would be unless you moved your mouse very, _very_ fast.

Comment: Sure... I'll add some other solutions as I will realising them. Check the answer.

Comment: That still wouldn't eliminate flickering, and if the user just held their mouse over the image, it would vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an image for your background, and an image for your cross-hairs, what if you used a div with a background image for your background instead, and then made the cross-hairs image a child of that div?

I haven't tested this, but since the cross-hair image would now be part of the content of the background div, I would imagine that it would no longer trigger a mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [**The pointer-events property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/) is exactly what you're looking for. It basically prevents an element from being the target of any sort of mouse-event so the elements underneath it can handle them instead. Parent elements can still react to the event.

***HOWEVER*** it is only supported in the later versions of Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, and it probably won't be in the [CSS specification until CSS4.](http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#pointer-events) It an awesome solution for supported browsers, but if you want to fix the issue in any version of IE or Opera you'll also need an alternate solution. I felt like it deserved a mention here though. :D

Comment: Damn you, IE, always thwarting my plans!